# how to use laravel 5.1 queue tried some code doesnot work

Tags: laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Storage;

class UploadFiles extends Job implements SelfHandling
{
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    protected $files;

    public function __construct($files)
    {
        //
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
        if(!empty($this->files)):

            foreach ($this->files as $key => $file) :
                # code...
                Storage::put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
            endforeach;
        endif;

    }
}
```

Inside controller

```
$files = $request->file('file');

$job = (new UploadFiles($files))
            ->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(15));
dispatch($job);
```

Queue does not respond m i doing something wrong please guide thanks a ton in advance. Also i can see no database entry inside job table neither response queue have data but image uploading stright forwardly

Comment: Have you setup a database queue? I think the default queue setting is `sync`, so all your jobs run instantly.

Comment: Not sure that it will help: `delay()` accept seconds. `->delay(15);`

Comment: Yup updated queue setting sync to database and @IndianCoding it does the same work straightly uploading files no delay working

Comment: @Jacob https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#pushing-jobs-onto-the-queue look at implements ShouldQueue and InteractsWithQueue trait.

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file, set `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`
and check your queue.php config file in config folder
set `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),`

after that run comand
`php artisan config:clear`
then try to dispatch job